# Bot Composer: Allow Interruptions only towards Cancel Dialog

Tags: botframework, artificial-intelligence

In my Chatbot project (on Bot Composer) I'm using CLU and I have many Dialogs for different intents.
I'd like to set allowInterruptions=true every time the user has to input something
But I'm only interested in Interrupt the conversation if the Cancel Dialog is going to be triggered; not towards every other Dialogs.

So, is there a way to allow interruptions only towards a certain dialog (or certain dialogs)?

Unfortunately it seems that just setting allowInterruptions=true make the conversation to be interrupts by any Intent.
I've seek for a solution on internet but I've just found answers that works for LUIS and not for CLU

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.